# Redirect back when back() is not null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, back

When I `dd(back())` it shows all inside back() and one of its key is **_previous** which I want to use.

My code:

```
if($request->session()->attributes['_previous'] !== NULL)
// go back
else
// go to specific page
```

My problem:

The **attributes** is protected and I couldn't use **_previous** to go back if it's not null.
Is there any suggestion I can use or some other approaches?

**Appreciation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use `back()`, because I can't see any scenario when you want to redirect and have `NULL` `back()` at the same time.

If you want to check referrer, you can you something like this:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
    Redirect::back();
}else{
    Redirect::route('main.page');
}
```

BTW, if you want to check something for `NULL` (not just `false`), you should use `is_null` function:
https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-null.php

Comment: Thanks dear @Alexey Mezenin, I don't know why I had forgot that Referer :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful )